# how to convert a (2,2) matrix to a (4,4) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am trying to double the size of a matrix without changing the values. Is there any dedicated function to do that? Here, I need to convert the matrix a to matrix b.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])

b = np.array([[1,1,2,2],
             [1,1,2,2],
             [3,3,4,4],
             [3,3,4,4]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) on both axes:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])

b =np.repeat(np.repeat(a, 2, axis=0), 2, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```